# Android - Override styles in android layout files

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I often see layout files in android that look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
        android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    />
```

That is actually the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` layout file.

What I want to know is if I use this layout in my application, is there a way to override the attributes mentioned in this file in my `styles.xml`. So for example I want to define a drawable for `checkMark` can I just do this in my application theme or in the styles.xml file? If so, how? Right now I just end up copying these files and changing the attributes as I need them.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible.
You just need to override this style attribute in your theme. For example if you want to change checkmark drawable:

`android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"`

put folowing in your theme:
`<item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/your_custom_selector_for_check_mark</item>`

You can create resources and selector using this website http://android-holo-colors.com/